# why junk code is appending while writing to text file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have stored txt. file contents in a list like, given below then I am 
trying to store it in  new.txt file , file writing is  working fine but 
instead of text I am getting junk code , How can i get rid of this Please 
help

```
  ListOfLines =['ÿþGroup:Test\n', '\n', 'Fields:³TESTNO³TESTNUM³\n', '\n', 
  '³37³DUCK³DAFFY³³³³2']

    fileName= open("path"+'//'+'TestFile+'.txt',"w+")
    for item in ListOfLines :
      x=(''.join([str(item)]))
      fileName.write(x)
```

OutPut

```
   片畯㩰䅐䥔久ൔഊ䘊敩摬㩳傳呁低䲳十乔䵁덅䥆乒䵁덅䥍乄䵁덅䥔䱔덅啓䙆塉傳呁䑉傳呁䥂呒덈䅐協塅亳䵁ㅅ傳呁䑉댱䍏啃䅐더䱈䰷䍏덋䅐䡔卉더䅐䍔䵏䆳䑄䕒卓䖳䡔䥎덃䥍剌
```

Comment: I had to provide encoding as well while opening file.  ,encoding='utf-8' then it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Encoding='UTF-8'` before reading this file. It will work